# Join lines in tmux's copy mode

Tags: tmux

In screen there is this really nice feature that you can join the lines you've selected in copy mode. You do this by hitting Shift + J in copy mode. If you press it again it will add a space as a separator and if you hit it again a comma.

Does tmux have this feature, or is there any way to mimic this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not selectable from inside *tmux*’s `copy-mode`, the `-s` flag to its `paste-buffer` command enables pasting with different separator strings (to be used in place of LF, where CR would normally be used).

```
paste-buffer -s ''
paste-buffer -s ' '
paste-buffer -s ,
```

You could bind any or all of these to different keys, or you could use `command-prompt` to bind a key that lets you enter a custom separator string before pasting:

```
bind-key C-p command-prompt -p separator: "paste-buffer -s '%%'"
```

Just be aware that any single quote characters in the string value will interact with the single quotes around the `%%` that mark the substitution location in the bound command. To get the above command to use `'` as the separator, you would need to type something like `'"'"'` at the prompt.